# how to call login page partially on index page in yii2

Tags: yii2

i want to call site/login page partially on site/index.php .
so i hv coded in site/index.php is below:

```
 if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
return $this->render('/site/login', [
'model' => $model,
```

]);
    }

and in site controller

```
$model = new LoginForm();

return $this->render('index', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
```

im getting error 
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Undefined variable: model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to make:

- logged in user to view - Index page
- non-logged in user to visit - Login page

Nothing to write anything in view.
Manage code in controller to render the view you needed.

So your controller code must be like:

```
$model = new LoginForm();
     if(isset(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)){
          return $this->render('login', [
                   'model' => $model,//Model is the user active record
                 ]);//render the view file located in **site folder** login.php **view file**
     }
    $model = Users::findOne(yii::$app->user->id);//model is the users model used to display controls in index.php view
    return $this->render('/site/index', ['model' => $model]);
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand but your problem looks like

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
return $this->render('/site/login', [
'model' => $model,
]); }
```

What is the model here?